# Hoare partition scheme in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I translated the Hoare partition scheme from a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) to Python:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
def partition(nums, low, high):
  pivot = nums[(high + low) // 2]
  i = low - 1
  j = high + 1

  while True:
    i += 1
    j -= 1

    while nums[i] < pivot:
      i += 1
    while nums[j] > pivot:
      j -= 1

    if i >= j:
      return j

    nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]    


nums = [14801, 338, 6389, 3209, 4825, 10818, 1768, 7669, 4545, 10930, 11810]
pivot_1 = partition(nums, 0, len(nums) - 1)
print(pivot_1)  # 6 ---> this should be 7, no?
print(nums)  # [4545, 338, 6389, 3209, 4825, 7669, 1768, 10818, 14801, 10930, 11810]

pivot_2 = partition(nums, 0, 6)
print(pivot_2)  # 2 ---> this looks ok
print(nums)  # [1768, 338, 3209, 6389, 4825, 7669, 4545, 10818, 14801, 10930, 11810]
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is my code not returning the correct pivot location?

Comment: Your Python `while` loops test and if false don’t execute the increment/decrement, where the wikipedian equivalent seem to always increment/decrement before doing the test?

Comment: @barny The OP also always increments/decrements before the test.

Comment: Well yes but that’s a) the same as the wikipedian and b) before either while loop, E.g. `while nums[i]<pivot:` will not execute the contained increment if the test is false, whereas the wikipedian will increment `i` before testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `this should be 7, no?`

No.

As the paragraph above the code at Wikipedia says:

> the pivot's final location is not necessarily at the index that is returned

You misunderstood the meaning of the returned index. It's just the partition border which you can then use for the recursive quicksorts.

Comment: Oh man... I've spent hours debugging my code and thinking about why it's not working. I thought this partitioning algorithm was interchangeable with the other one

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with python syntax, but in java I implement this as follows

```
private static int partition(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
        int pivot = arr[(low+high)/2];
        int i = low-1, j = high+1;
        while(true) {
          do { i++; } while(arr[i] < pivot);
          do { j--; } while(arr[j] > pivot);
          if (i < j) swap(arr, i, j);
          else return j;
        }
```

It may help you to implement same logic in python.

Comment: Your implementation returns an incorrect result for the input mentioned in the original question as well.